# escape #{{}} in freemarker template

Tags: angularjs, freemarker

I am using angular js and freemarker together, in the template I wrote a `<a>` tag whose `href` attr starts with a `#` so I can config route in angular such as:

```
<a href="#/edit/user">
```

but when writing the template with angularJS template, it seems there is some conflict (with freemarker syntax and angularJS template syntax together):

```
 <li ng-repeat="tab in tabs">
    <a href="#{{tab.url}}"> {{tab.title}} </a>
 </li>
```

if I wrote like above the freemarker template will fail to parse with this exception:

```
freemarker.core.ParseException: Parsing error in template "mis/newindex.ftl" in line 21, column 80:
Encountered "}", but was expecting one of:
    ","
    ":"
    "."
    "["
    "("
    "?"
    "!"
    <TERMINATING_EXCLAM>
    "??"
    "+"
    "-"
    "*"
    "/"
    "%"
    "!="
    "="
    "=="
    ">="
    <ESCAPED_GTE>
    ">"
    <ESCAPED_GT>
    <LESS_THAN_EQUALS>
    <LESS_THAN>
    ".."
    <AND>
    <OR>
```

I know `#{{tab.url}}` should be the one cause the problem, but how could I bypass this issue?

---

I have by pass this by add a method in the angular controller to build the url prefixed with `#`

```
function completeUrl(url){
    return '#' + url;
}

<a href={{completeUrl(tab.url)}}> {{tab.title}} </a>
```

but still, I want to find a more elegant solution.

Comment: @bipinpatel thanks for reply, but I don't know how to  create a plunkr with `freemarker`, and it's more like a freemarker issue

Comment: @bipinpatel http://pastebin.com/tVU9SEQE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** Since FreeMarker 2.3.28 you can configure FreeMarker to only use `${...}`, not `#{...}`, by setting the `interpolation_syntax` configuration setting to `dollar` (in the Java API: `Configuration cfg; ... cfg.setInterpolationSyntax(Configuration.DOLLAR_INTERPOLATION_SYNTAX)`). Then `#{...}` is just static text for FreeMarker. Do not confuse this setting with the `tag_syntax` setting. BTW, it's also possible to use `[=...]` as interpolation syntax, in case `${...}` also clashes with something (like with ES6 string interpolations). See also: https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/dgui_misc_alternativesyntax.html

That's an unfortunate clash with FreeMarker's `#{}`, which is even deprecated and is only recognized for backward compatibility, but the parser is not configurable to ignore it. The shortest (even if ugly) solution I can think of is `${'#'}{{}}`.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is with `href` value, you can solve this issue by using `ngHref` directive.

The code should be like:

```
<li ng-repeat="tab in tabs">
    <a ng-href="#/{{tab.url}}"> {{tab.title}} </a>
</li>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I already have a prefix `/` in `tab.url`, so this will not solve the problem :-(

Comment: Then you can simply try as `#{{tab.url}}`.

Comment: I have tried that, since freemarker template will be parsed before angularJs template, didn't get any luck, thanks, though